# Error recording json file. Open and replace and save

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to replace the special python characters, but replacing is not working for me.

```
def enviarwebservice():
    url = "https://server/api/v1/a032ccb8-8c32-4c4e-976a-07f5e9a64e26"       
    files=ls4("c:/validacionFX/","*.json") #*******ruta donde se genera el json*********    
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if 1==1:
            for archivo in files:        
                if os.path.isfile(archivo):      
                    with io.open(archivo,'r',encoding='utf8')as file:
                        cadenaId=(os.path.basename(archivo)).split('-') #--es una tipo lista.   
                        print("Antes de leer")   
                        file_data=file.read().replace('\\"', '\"').replace('\\n','\n').replace('\\',' ')
                        with io.open(archivo,'w',encoding='utf8')as f:
                            f.write(file_data)
                            json_data=json.load(f)        
                            payload=json.dumps(json_data,indent=4)
```

Comment: Where is the `except` that goes with `try`?

Comment: Why are you replacing characters in a JSON file?

Comment: What is `if 1==1:` for? If this is a placeholder for some other condition, use `if True:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read what you just wrote, you need to open the file in `w+` mode, not `w` mode. You also have to rewind the file, otherwise you start reading from the end of what you wrote, and there's nothing there.

```
                        with io.open(archivo,'w+',encoding='utf8')as f:
                            f.write(file_data)
                            f.seek(0)
                            json_data=json.load(f)
```

But there's no reason to read it back from the file. You already have the JSON in `file_data`, you can load that.

Also, you should close the first file handle before writing back out to the same file. Take the second `with` block outside of the first one.

```
            for archivo in files:        
                if os.path.isfile(archivo):      
                    with io.open(archivo,'r',encoding='utf8')as file:
                        cadenaId=(os.path.basename(archivo)).split('-') #--es una tipo lista.   
                        print("Antes de leer")   
                        file_data=file.read().replace('\\"', '\"').replace('\\n','\n').replace('\\',' ')
                    with io.open(archivo,'w',encoding='utf8')as f:
                        f.write(file_data)
                    json_data=json.loads(file_data)
```

However, I think what you're doing may be misguided in the first place. You're replacing escaped characters with non-escaped characters, but escaping is necessary when special characters are embedded in JSON.

Comment: I get another error, that the file is open. I need the change to be in the same file and with f.load () /invalid json: [winError 32] The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Try taking the code that writes to the file outside the first `with` block, so that the reading file is closed before you try to write.